# SocketException( Connection timed out ) is thrown when i run my android app on a real device

Tags: android, socketexception, connection-timeout

My android app needs to perform Http requests through HttpClient.
i've tested on the emulator and it works fine.  but when i do it on a real device with WIFI activated, sometimes ANR occurred, and sometimes SocketException is thrown.
it seems that the device is not able to connect the server.
logcat print-out is as follows

in addition, the package name for the app is "com.tim.wirelessorder"

```
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:115)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:244)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at com.tim.wirelessorder.util.net.HttpUtil.getHttpResponse(HttpUtil.java:43)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at com.tim.wirelessorder.ui.SignIn$BnListener.onClick(SignIn.java:117)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 09:51:17.803: W/System.err(2307):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-03 09:51:17.810: W/System.err(2307):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 09:51:28.289: W/KeyCharacterMap(2307): Can't open keycharmap file
06-03 09:51:28.289: W/KeyCharacterMap(2307): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ilitek_ts.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65538.devname='ilitek_ts'
06-03 09:51:28.289: W/KeyCharacterMap(2307): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

this problem is really disturbing, because i'm not developing an app which only can be run on an emulator. that won't make any sense. can anybaby figure out what problem is?

my code is here.

```
                    HttpPost request = HttpUtil.getHttpPost(url);
                    List<BasicNameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                    BasicNameValuePair vName = new BasicNameValuePair(
                            "name", name);
                    list.add(vName);
                    BasicNameValuePair vPwd = new BasicNameValuePair("pwd",
                            pwd);
                    list.add(vPwd);
                    // Log.e("result", "kk:");
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                    HttpResponse response = HttpUtil
                            .getHttpResponse(request);
// -------- the line above throws the SocketException. this is a static method. the code is added below.
```

======

```
public static HttpGet getHttpGet(String url) {
    Log.e("url", url);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    return request;
}


public static HttpPost getHttpPost(String url) {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    return request;
}
public static HttpResponse getHttpResponse(HttpGet request)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    // Log.e("http", "in ");
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
    // Log.e("http", (response == null) + " ");
    return response;
}


public static HttpResponse getHttpResponse(HttpPost request)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
// ------- and here it performs a HttpPost request, and it seems the request fails to be sent.
        return response;
    }
```

this is the do-post code on the server. the servlet receives the request, and get the name, pwd parameter from the  client entered by users on UI. then servlet activates a DAO which uses the name, pwd to do queries in MySQL. you can see a "System.out.println(name)" line by which i want to make sure whether the servlet obtains the request. and when i test the code on a real device, the console doesn't give any print-out. and i think this means the servlet doesn't receive the request.

```
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
    System.out.println(name);

    UserDao dao = new UserDaoImpl();

    byte[] r = dao.query(name, pwd);
    out.write(r);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: i've added my code. but since it works fine on emulator. probably it's not the code problem.

Comment: on which line the exception is thrown and what is the URL you're trying to access ?

Comment: on this line " HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request)"

Comment: i also marked where the exception is thrown in the code above.

Comment: the URL links to a Servlet on my Server, a J2EE project.

Comment: the URL is not a local, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using another method of sending HTTP request:

```
url = "http://<your URL>";
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
Log.d("DEBUG", "url=" + url);
URLConnection lu = urlObj.openConnection();

//optional - send parameters
String data = URLEncoder.encode("param", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"); //optional - send parameters
// Send data
lu.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(lu.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
//end of "optional"

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lu.getInputStream()));
String line = "", res = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    res += line;
}

wr.flush();
wr.close();
Log.d("DEBUG", "res=" + res);
```

Comment: i tried. but it didn't work. when it goes to OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()), it stops. then a couple of seconds later, the SockeException( the operation timed out ) is thrown.

Comment: i tried many times. your code works fine on the emulator. but just can't be run on a real device. i don't get it. what's the difference?

Comment: i've updated my question and add the server-side code. please check if there's any problem. thanks.

Comment: and on the access-log (apache/tomcat) do you see the call ?

Comment: It sounds like the HTTP call is not made from the device, and not that the tomcat doesn't respond. You can make an easy test: use firefox's POSTER to post/get the same http request and see if the tomcat respond. if it does then the problem is in the application.

Comment: are you sure that you have the permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 in the manifest file ?

Comment: first of all, i do have the permission. and tomcat works well using a ie explorer.

Comment: it suddenly occurred to me that there may be some problems with the ip address. because when i use the emulator to test, the emulator is on my PC which also act as the server.
but the smartphone is totally another device...

Comment: I've fixxed the problem. But I still not clear what the exact cause is. when using the emulator, I use the ip from Ethernet Adapter. and the app performs well but as i said it can't work on a real device. and i test the app this time with ip from wireless adapter, unexpectedly my app fails to work on the emulator but works fine on the device instead!
since I have no knowledge about network, I can't figure out the cause. I hope you can explain it. Thank you!

Comment: the first thing I asked you was " what is the URL you're trying to access ? " - it has nothing to do with the smartphone - try accessing the same URL from a different computer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you got me wrong. The URL is like "http://"+"my pc's ip addr"+"8080/"+... .(my pc works as server) and key point is the ip address. I trid accessing the URL from a different computer. And when the ip is a wireless adapter one( i hope you get what i mean, i'm not familiar with net terminology ), it's ok. But when the ip is an Ethernet Adapter ip, my computer can't connect to the server. However the funny thing is, when I try this on the emulator, the result is totally the opposite. the emulater can only connect to the server with Ethernet Adapter ip. This really confuses me.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "Ethernet Adapter ip". But I'm pretty sure that if you'll try to run the emulator on a different computer (from the server) it won't work. Please try.

Comment: thank you. anyway, the problem is fixxed and my app now can be run on a real device, although there's somthing still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

When ever I get this its when I get no data connection. Also check you have the right permissions cause that can do it to.

Comment: there's no permission denial. and i do remember to have the permissions added