# java httpclient returning 404 as the response code

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am trying to run an andriod application from emulator , but whenever i send a valid url request it is showing 404 as status code . I have following code.

if i use

```
http://10.0.2.2/api/ca/entry/?format=json&username=pragya
```

from emulator browser , it is returning fine.

```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/api/ca/entry/?format=json&username=pragya");
                    try {

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        Integer i =response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                        Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, i.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

EDIT................
The manifest file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andriod.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: maybe the following thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867434/socketexception-connection-timed-out-is-thrown-when-i-run-my-android-app-on-a/10902080#10902080

Comment: `package="com.andriod.test"` maybe this typo causes the problems? Check that it matches the package name of your classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try two thing one shuold be solution

1 - check entry is there in manifest `android.permission.INTERNET`

2- try to open the same in phone native browser

- 2-a if get open then it's fine

  2-b if not get open try that url in desktop browser

Comment: ohh gr8 you already entry in manifest... so please let use also know about  2a and 2b?

Comment: 2-a) I have tried it emulator native browser, it should return json output in browser, but it is prompting me to download but its not 404, it is 200 as url is callable from native browser
2-b) from desktop browser using http://localhost/api/entry/... it is running well

Comment: thank you your testing way help me to figure out error.. i am new to andriod programming , my mistake was " i was misunderstood that localhost:8000 will be handelled by 10.0.2.2 infact need to add the port also there i.e 10.0.2.2:8000, sorry i wasted all of you guys time for such stupid mistake

Comment: Hi guys, I'm facing the same problem... in phone native browser it works fine but from the Android app the response is 404... what should I do? URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/my/resource

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that server is up with application to which you are connecting.
[More info for http 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)